# Convert an int to a NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have an int called `xpos`. I want to make a NSTextView display that int. I know in python there is a `str()` function that does this. Is there an Objective-c method like this? I want to make the int into a NSString so I can do something like this :

```
[self.textview insertText:str(xpos)];
```

PS: I need it as an int for the `* / + -`, `++`, `--`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat : @"%d", xpos];
```